# No overflow exception for int in C#?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

I had this weird experience with problem number 10 on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) (great site by the way). The assignment was to calculate the sum of all the prime numbers below two million.

I used an int for the sum, and my algorith produced an answer, but when i pasted it to verify the answer, it was wrong.

It turned out that the result was too big to fit in an int, but wouldn't this cause an overflow error or something? Instead, it just returned a value far off from the real answer.

When I changed the type to long, everything was hunky dory.

Comment: Do you really want every integer operation to check for overflow?

Comment: Well, it shure would have saved me some time in this particular case ;)

Comment: In this case, yes. The vast majority of operations can't possibly overflow though. It would be interesting if the compiler could prove this and disable checking as a result, but I very much doubt it does.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

C# integer operations don’t throw exceptions upon overflow by default. You can achieve that via the project settings, or by making the calculation `checked`:

```
int result = checked(largeInt + otherLargeInt);
```

Now the operation will throw.

The opposite is `unchecked`, which makes any operation explicitly unchecked. Obviously, this only makes sense when you’ve got checked operations enabled in the project settings.

Comment: Unless you're in debug mode, where I think int operations are checked by default.

Comment: Nope. I ran in debug mode when this occured.

Comment: Oh. I stand corrected. I was sure that my Project Euler projects told me about overflows in debug mode. :/

Comment: "Obviously, this only makes sense when you’ve got checked operations enabled in the project settings." ... or you want to evaluate an `unchecked` expression in a `checked` context. You can certainly nest the blocks.

Comment: Konrad what happens to result value when it overflows - lets say you are adding up a bunch of bytes for a checksum and checksum result is a byte. You don't care if it overflows you just want to keep adding bytes. Does it result go to 0 on overflow and just keep accumulating?

Comment: @NealDavis Inside a `checked` block or expression, an `OverflowException` is thrown. If you don’t care about overflows, don’t check for them. Your checksum example would be a typical use-case where you *don’t* want to check for overflows. This will normally roll around (not go to zero). However, note that C# (and other languages) by default do something cheeky called “integer promotion”. The result of adding two bytes is an *integer*. If you print that directly, the result may be larger than what can fit inside a `byte`. You need to reassign it to a byte (or cast it) to truncate it.

Answer (score 27):

In C# an [`OverflowException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx) is not thrown (in VB the exception is thrown per default).

To get the excpetion you have to embed your code in a `checked` context:

```
byte value = 241;
checked
{
    try 
    {
        sbyte newValue = (sbyte) value;
        Console.WriteLine("Converted the {0} value {1} to the {2} value {3}.", 
            value.GetType().Name, value, 
            newValue.GetType().Name, newValue);
    }
    catch (OverflowException) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0} > {1}.", value, SByte.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

MSDN explains in more detail:

> For the arithmetic, casting, or
>   conversion operation to throw an
>   OverflowException, the operation must
>   occur in a checked context. By
>   default, arithmetic operations and
>   overflows in Visual Basic are checked;
>   in C#, they are not. If the operation
>   occurs in an unchecked context, the
>   result is truncated by discarding any
>   high-order bits that do not fit into
>   the destination type.

Answer (score 23):

It's because, by default C# do not throw any exception for integer overflow as well as underflow. There are couple of things you can do here.

> Option 1

You have to enable the exception to be thrown by go to
Project => properties => Build tab => Advanced => check for arithmetic overflow underflow.(make sure you tick the option)

[image]

Make sure you tick the option

> Option 2

Use a checked block and throw an overflow exception to handle the situation. A sample code snippet would be

```
        try
        {
            checked
            {
                int y = 1000000000;
                short x = (short)y;
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Overflow");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

I have already added a comment, but maybe it would be interesting for some of you:

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) tells us:

> Integer arithmetic overflow either
> throws an OverflowException or
> discards the most significant bits of
> the result

but

> Decimal arithmetic overflow always
> throws an OverflowException.

also

> When integer overflow occurs, what
> happens depends on the execution
> context, which can be checked or
> unchecked. In a checked context, an
> OverflowException is thrown. In an
> unchecked context, the most
> significant bits of the result are
> discarded and execution continues.
> Thus, C# gives you the choice of
> handling or ignoring overflow.

Comment: Which makes sense, since decimals are mostly used for either currency or scientific calculations, and you would probably rather have them throw  then fail silently.

Answer (score 6):

By default, C# does not check for arithmetic overflow on integers. You can change this with the `/checked` [compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fdbz5xd%28VS.71%29.aspx) or by enabling "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow" in Visual Studio (project properties - Build - Advanced).

You can use [`checked` and `unchecked` keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx) to override the default on a case-by-case basis. If you rely on checking taking place in a piece of code, explicitly enabling it using `checked` would be a good idea.

```
int j = checked(i * 2);

checked
{
    int j = i * 2;
    // Do more stuff
}
```

Note that floating point operations never throw an `OverflowException`, and decimal operations always throw an `OverflowException`. See also [C# operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can set `checked` directly in `csproj` by adding:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It's the equivalent of ticking that `Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow` checkbox in the designer.