# Project euler number 10#

Tags: c#

```
The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.

Find the sum of all the primes below two million.
```

And my answer is:

```
bool IsRishoni;
int soap = 0;
for (int i = 3; i < 2000000; i++)
{
    IsRishoni = true;
    for (int a = 2; (a <= Math.Sqrt(i)) && (IsRishoni); a++)
    {
        if (i % a == 0)
            IsRishoni = false;
    }
    if (IsRishoni)
    {
        soap = i + soap;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(soap + 2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Why is this not working? the answer I got is 1179908154 ... help please.

Comment: And what is the answer you should get?

Comment: He doesn't know the answer yet (that's the problem he is trying to solve!), I won't spoil it but the answer is < 100000

Comment: @DD59 No, it's greater than that.

Comment: Oops, I lied, I pulled the wrong answer: ~ 150,000,000,000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
soap = i + soap;
```

with

```
soap = checked(i + soap);
```

..and the problem should be exposed.

This question has more details: [No overflow exception for int in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c)

Comment: Um, the problem is described in that question you've been given a link to. Have you read it?

Comment: I think the point of Euler problems is to hands-on experience various aspects of computing, so I'm not gonna tell you precisely what the problem is. Try out the change above, and continue from there.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer (stored in `soap`) is a value greater than `int.Maxvalue` (2,147,483,647).

Your answer is ~ 150,000,000,000

In other words you need to use an data type which is bigger than that.

```
long.MaxValue = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
int.Maxvalue = 2,147,483,647
```

Answer (score 1):

The result you’re after might be too large to represent through a 32-bit signed integer (`int`).

Let’s first determine the result’s upper bound by assuming that *all* numbers are prime. Through [summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), we know that the sum of all numbers up to `N` (inclusive) is `N * (N + 1) / 2`; thus, the upper bound for the sum of all primes up to 2,000,000 is 2,000,001,000,000. This is larger than the maximum value allowed by `int`, 2,147,483,647, so you’re probably getting a numeric overflow which is silently ignored.

If you wanted a more accurate estimate of your answer, you could use the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), which states that the probability of a random integer between 0 and `N` being prime is approximately `1 / ln(N)`. Combining this with our previous formula, the approximate sum of all primes up to `N` is `N * (N + 1) / (2 * ln(N))`. For 2,000,000, this evaluates to around 138,000,000,000, which is still larger than the maximum value for `int`.

To resolve your problem, you could simply switch the integral data type you’re using for the `soap` variable to a 64-bit integer representation, such as `long`. Its maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, so it would definitely be able to represent your number.

```
long soap = 0;
```

On a separate note: Since you’re working with *sequences* of primes, you could achieve a huge performance gain (at least 100×) if you change your implementation to a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).