# strange no error within C# application

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, int, jit

I have a c# application in which i have this code :

```
 public static void Main()
        {
            int i = 2147483647;
            int j = i+1;
            Console.WriteLine(j);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

The result is : `-2147483648`

I know that every integer must be `< 2147483648`. So

- Why I don't have a compilation or runtime error? like in this exemple

[image: img]

- What is the reason of the negative sign?

thanks

Comment: This question has already been answered **many** times... (Edit: I mean the overflow question) For example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c?lq=1)

Comment: @ThreeFx what is the problem so? do u mean it's duplicated ?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler defaults to unchecked arithmetic; you have simply overflown and looped around, thanks to [two's-complement storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049774/23354).

This fails at runtime:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int i = 2147483647;
    int j = checked((int)(i + 1)); // <==== note "checked"
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This can also be enabled globally as a compiler-switch.

Answer (score 2):

As Christos says, the negative sign comes from integer overflow. The reason you do net get an error is because the compiler does not evaluate expressions for overflowing values.

```
 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 2^31-1
+0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1
=1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 -2^31
```

The reason for this is that the leftmost bit is the sign bit, it determines whether the `int` is positive or negative. 0 is positive, 1 is negative. If you add one to the largest possible number, you essentially change the sign bit and get the smallest representable number. The reason for this is that integers use [two's complement storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

To check if the value overflows, do:

```
int j = checked(i + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason of the negative sign?

You have a negative sign, because you have exceeded the maximum integer value and the next integer is the lowest integer that can be represented.

> Why I don't have a compilation or runtime error?

You don't have a complilation error, because this is not an error. Also, this is not a runtime error. You just add one to the `i` in the runtime. Since the value of `i` is the maximum integer value that can be stored in a variable of type `int` and since the circular nature of the integers in programming, you will get the lowest integer that can be stored in a variable of type `int`.

(A variable of type `int` can store 32-bit integers).

Furthermore, by **default** you in C# integer operation don't throw exceptions upon overflow. You could alter this either from *project settings* or using a `checked` statement, as it is already have been pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c).

Comment: The result is false, so why I don't have an error here `int j = (int)(i+1);` ??

Comment: @Lamloumi The result is not false, it is correct as far as integers are concerned

Answer (score 1):

> Why I don't have a compilation or runtime error?

Because compiler can determine that you have assigned a larger than `int.MaxValue` value to the variable. Since it is hard coded. But for `i+1` compiler can't execute the code to determine that the result of this calculation would be greater than `int.MaxValue`

> What is the reason of the negative sign?

It is because of **integer overflow**.

See: [checked (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx)

> By default, an expression that contains **only constant values causes
>   a compiler error** if the expression produces a value that is outside
>   the range of the destination type. If the expression contains one or
>   more non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow.

Comment: In runtime , why I don't have an error?? for the compilation it seems clear

Comment: @Lamloumi, at runtime you will get an exception `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`. Errors are at compile time. *(If you have checked keyword)*