# .NET vs Mono: different results for conversion from 2^32 as double to int

Tags: c#, .net, mono

**TL;DR** Why does the `(int)Math.Pow(2,32)` return `0` on Mono and `Int32.MinValue` on .NET ?

---

While testing my .NET-written code on Mono I've stumbled upon the following line:

`var i = X / ( (int)Math.Pow(2,32) );`

well that line doesn't make much sense of course and I've already changed it to `long`.

I was however curious why didn't my code throw `DivideByZeroException` on .NET so I've checked the return value of that expression on both Mono and .NET

Can anyone please explain me the results?

Comment: The `Math.Pow` is a distraction. Your real question is why does `(int)(((double)Int32.MaxValue) + 1)` equal `Int32.MinValue` on .NET and 0 on mono.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No overflow exception for int in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c)

Comment: I voted as duplicate for the question on overflow.  I'm not sure of the internals for mono, but C# doesn't throw overflow exceptions by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c

Comment: Doesn't seem like a duplicate of that to me. This isn't asking why no exception is thrown; it's asking why the unchecked result is different in Mono from .NET. As for that, IMHO the question is academic; the documentation promises only that ["the result is an unspecified value of the destination type"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx), so each platform is free to do whatever it wants.

Comment: @ps2goat: `DivideByZeroException` is not an overflow exception.

Comment: Guys I believe it's not about overflow exceptions as the operation is called in "unchecked" context (default) so no exception is expected behavior

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa, sorry, I misspoke.  .NET does not evaluate to zero, so you aren't dividing by zero.

Comment: @ps2goat: he knows that. He wants to know why .NET doesn't not evaluate to zero.

Comment: Are you sure?  SO `var max = Int32.MaxValue;
var assertion = max + 1 == Int32.MinValue;` 
Assertion is false in Mono. That sounds like it's out of whack with the C# spec.

Comment: It almost looks like once overflow occurs, the value is set to `Int32.MinValue`

Comment: @NathanCooper, I agree.  If Mono is supposed to copy .NET, Mono should be the one answering questions.

Comment: @NathanCooper No, that's absolutely not what Mono does. Try it. `assertion` will be true. (I did try it.) What you have is different from what's in the question, and what's in the question does not have a well-defined result in C#, as pointed out by Peter Duniho.

Comment: @hvd. Yep, just read  Peter Duniho's comment. Of course it's to do with the casting. I had no idea it would be unspecified. Interesting. I would like to see the internal implementations, there must be a reason.

Comment: I think @PeterDuniho should make that the answer.

Comment: Maybe you want to test with mono master:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26219

Comment: There can be hardware differences as well: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26213#c3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"the result is an unspecified value of the destination type". I thought it would be interesting to see what's actually happening in the .NET implementation.

It's to do with the [OpCodes.Conv_I4 Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_i4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in IL: `" Conversion from floating-point numbers to integer values truncates the number toward zero. When converting from a float64 to a float32, precision can be lost. If value is too large to fit in a float32 (F), positive infinity (if value is positive) or negative infinity (if value is negative) is returned. If overflow occurs converting one integer type to another, the high order bits are truncated"`  It does once again say overflow is unspecified however.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO the question is academic; the documentation promises only that ["the result is an unspecified value of the destination type"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx), so each platform is free to do whatever it wants.

One should be very careful when casting results that might overflow. If there is a possibility of that, and it's important to get a specific result instead of whatever arbitrary implementation a given platform has provided, one should use the [checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) keyword and catch any `OverflowException` that might occur, handling it with whatever explicit behavior is desired.