# Why C# compiler is not throwing any error?

Tags: c#

Following is a piece of code:

```
    {
        int counter = 1;
        try
        {
            while (true) 
                counter*=2;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, after a few iterations, value of 'counter' becomes 0.
I don't understand why it is so?

Comment: How many is a "few iterations"? So it is not reaching the Exception part of your code when you are expecting it to? We need a bit of more an explanation in your question, but it does sound like an integer overflow

Comment: 0 * 2 = 0 - no error there.....nothing to catch....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relation between the question's title and the body of the question. What is it you're asking about? Why it becomes 0? How does that relate to the C# compiler throwing an error? What would the error be about?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/2056457/507793

Comment: `counter` overflows when the value assigned to it is larger than `int.MaxValue` and gets rolled back to `0`

Comment: Why would the compiler throw an error? If the syntax is correct, the behaviour doesn't make any difference.

Comment: very much unclear what are you asking. rethink on your question

Comment: @JohnOdom should be 32 :)

Comment: The code is syntactically correct, so no error.

Comment: @DStanley I figured :P. Just wanted OP to add more info to the question so we can be 100% sure with our answers/comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When counter reach the int.MaxValue then counter * 2 becomes a negative integer.

Then when counter reach int.MinValue then counter * 2 becomes 0.

Then on each iteration you have 0 * 2 = 0, no exception to throw.

Comment: Actually it will go up to 1073741824, then `int.MinValue`, then 0.

Answer (score 10):

Use `checked` for the *overflow exception* to be thrown:

```
checked { 
  int counter = 1;

  try {
    while (true) 
      counter *= 2;
    }
  catch (Exception) { // Actually, on integer overflow
    Console.WriteLine(counter);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Edit: what's going on.

Fact: integer *multiplication* by **2** is equal to *left shift* by **1**, i.e.

```
counter * 2 == counter << 1
```

In your case (let `counter` be represented as binary)

```
 00000000000000000000000000000001 // initial, just 1 
 00000000000000000000000000000010 // 1st itteration (shifted by 1)
 00000000000000000000000000000100 // 2nd itteration (shifted by 2)
 ...
 10000000000000000000000000000000 // 31st itteration (shifted by 31)
```

the next, 32nd itteration can cause either *integer overflow* or when 
   `unchecked` just push the leftmost 1 out

```
 0000000000000000000000000000000 // 32nd itterartion, now we have 0
```