# why left shift operator prints different results for hard coded values and Big-integer

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

when using left shift and Big-integer i get different results to when i use hard coded number, why is that and how can it be overcome?

```
    BigInteger num = 1779033703;
    BigInteger result = num << 30;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.WriteLine(1779033703 << 30);
```

**Result**

1910222893216694272

-1073741824

Comment: Because the "hard coded value" is an `int` and they can only hold 32 bits to represent a number.  `BigInteger` exists specifically to allow you to work with larger integer values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No overflow exception for int in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Because with `1779033703 << 30` on a regular `int` (a 32-bit signed integer), you are hitting the overflow, hence it starts from `int.MinValue` again. The `BigInteger` can handle much larger values, and is thus not affected by overflow.

Try to use a `long` (a 64-bit signed integer), and you will see you get the same result as with the `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. how can i use << and big number(bigger than int) but get the same results as it was int but not getting the overflow exception? with JS it is possible.. but i can't with c#

Comment: In this case a `long` would do, as stated in my answer.

Comment: let me clarify my question. if i use JS compare to BigInteger in C# i get different results. the JS give me negative numbers while C# very large ones

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto so what can i do with big numbers to get the same results as JS gives me?

Comment: @harelbracha You should [edit] your question and include the JS code and output

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the wrong result in JS? The one calculated by `BigInteger` is the correct one.

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman long is giving me the same results as BigIntegers

Comment: So that one is correct. The negative numbers are wrong.

Comment: What JS result?

Comment: So you have that code in C# already, right? What more do you ask?

Comment: i made a mess. what i want is to be able to deal with big numbers in C# using << operator but get the same results as JS(the wrong ones) without getting overflow exception

Comment: @harelbracha That's not possible since the exact same is happening in JS and C#, an integer overflow.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman  i don't have it yet, as if i put the hard coded value in int variable i get overflow exception(the code is much more complex and i can't write hard coded numbers)

Comment: @ Camilo Terevinto  var a = 1779033703; print(a << 30)   results: -1073741824