# .NET RT bug? Explicit conversion from float to int causes overflow, but no exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, overflow, ecma

I stumbled across quite an interesting behavior and want to ask, if somebody can explain me why the following is not throwing an `OverflowException` in .NET languages (checked with .NET 6):

```
var f = (float)int.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(f); // 2.147484E+09, totally fine so far
var i = (int)f;
Console.WriteLine(i); // -2147483648, which is negative, no OverflowException
```

So, I understand that casting `int.MaxValue` to `float` will not be an exact representation of an integer and I understand too, that casting the result back to `Int32` will most likely be not the same as what I had before, due to how floating point values are represented in memory.
This is all fine.

But my naive expectation was, that a thought-through and beautiful language like C# would actually cause a `System.OverflowException` for the second conversion, which is apparently not the case.

In comparison, writing something like the following does already give us a compile time error, though basically doing the same (I know, I know, this is checked by the compiler and is not really related to the RT behavior):

```
int i = (int)(float)int.MaxValue;
// CS0221 Constant value '2.147484E+09' cannot be converted to a 'int' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)
```

So my question is: Why is the .NET RT not throwing an exception here? Is this defined behavior according to the spec? I was not able to find anything in [ECMA 334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/) which explains this discovery.
On the contrary, check chapter "11.3.2 Explicit numeric conversions":

> For a conversion from float or double to an integral type [...] the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this
> integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the
> conversion. Otherwise, a System.OverflowException is thrown.

I'm sure that I cannot be the first person stumbling across such behavior, but I did not find anything on SO explaining me that and I don't believe that this is a RT bug which was never discovered in the history of .NET.

Comment: You didn't read that section of the spec properly *"For a conversion from float or double to an integral type, the processing depends on the overflow-
checking context (§12.7.14) in which the conversion takes place......"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No overflow exception for int in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c)

Comment: @Charlieface No, I've read that, but I was not aware that the default checking context for a project created with VS does not consider arithmetic overflows. As I wrote in the comment to SuRGeoNix answer, I was used to the default behavior of the old csproj file format, in which it was enabled for debug configurations by default. I did not notice that this changed with the template for the new format. Your link to the other question is helpful though, thanks.

Comment: Top answer of that question begins *"C# integer operations don’t throw exceptions upon overflow by default. You can achieve that via the project settings, or by making the calculation checked:"* which seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manually enable 'Check for arithmetic overflow' from project properties -> build -> advanced

Comment: Well, this was a fast answer - thank you. Allowed me to google for more info. For anyone interested, the option in the .csproj is called `CheckForOverflowUnderflow` and looking at older projects on our repo server, it seems that it was by default set to `true` for debug and `false` in release configs of autogenerated .csproj files in the old csproj format.

Comment: ... or use a `checked {}` context, which is the same thing just local