# Trying to implement memoization fibonacci series, it works till fib(46), but after that its returning negative values

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am trying to implement a dynamic programming problem for getting the nth number in the fibbonacci series. I am getting the output till 46th element but after that i am getting negative numbers as output..

```
int fib(int n, Dictionary<int, int> memo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n +" "+ memo + "Hello");
    if (memo.ContainsKey(n))
    {
        return memo[n];
    }
    if (n<=2) return 1;
    else
    {
        memo[n] =  fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
        return memo[n];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Fib " + fib(7, new Dictionary<int, int>()));
Console.WriteLine("Fib " + fib(46, new Dictionary<int, int>()));
Console.WriteLine("Fib " + fib(50, new Dictionary<int, int>()));
```

**Output **:
Fib 13
Fib 1836311903
Fib -298632863

**Expected output** :
fib 12586269025

Comment: Try to use long instead of int

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the maximum value of an `int` (`Int32`) is `2147483647`.
You already know that the value you are expecting is `12586269025` which exceeds this value.

The simple solution is to change the value data type to `long` (`Int64`) or `Int128` if you want to go to 93 `12200160415121876738`

```
Int128 fib(int n, Dictionary<int, Int128> memo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} [{1}] {2}", n, memo.Count, memo.Count > 0 ? memo.Last().ToString() : "??");
    if (memo.ContainsKey(n))
    {
        return memo[n];
    }
    if (n <= 2) return 1;
    else
    {
        memo[n] = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
        return memo[n];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Fib " + fib(7, new Dictionary<int, Int128>()));
Console.WriteLine("Fib " + fib(46, new Dictionary<int, Int128>()));
Console.WriteLine("Fib " + fib(50, new Dictionary<int, Int128>()));
Console.WriteLine("Fib " + fib(92, new Dictionary<int, Int128>()));
Console.WriteLine("Fib " + fib(93, new Dictionary<int, Int128>()));
```

Why does this matter, or more importantly, why doesn't this fail when the result of `fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo)` is greater than the maximum value the data type can hold?

The answer is that by default the C# compiler doesn't do that. There is a healthy discussion here: [No overflow exception for int in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2056445/1690217) but it is something that we need to be mindful of as c# developers if we are dealing with integers of large magnitudes (positive *and/or* negative).

If you wrap the addition expression in `checked()` then we can force this to fail with an exception at runtime, rather than leaving us with a seemingly valid value:

`memo[n] = checked(fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo))`;

[image: c# with arithmetic overflow checking]

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of an integer is `2147483647` (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=net-7.0)). As your expected number, `12586269025`, is larger than the max size of an `int` value, the value stored in the `int` will loop into negative values.

To resolve this, you can use a `long` instead of an `int` to store the value as it has a [much larger max size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.maxvalue?view=net-7.0) at `9223372036854775807`. If you really need the space, you can even use a `ulong` - unsigned long that wont support negative numbers but has a [max size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64.maxvalue?view=net-7.0) of `18446744073709551615`.

Need to go higher than that? I think you will have to refactor your code at that point to generate the number.

Comment: You forgot about [`UInt128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128?view=net-7.0) ;)

Comment: That exists?! I've been missing out.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum (signed) `int` value is 2147483647. When you go over this, it can reverse back and starts from -2147483647.

You can use `long` or even `ulong` types to be able to go further but you will face the same issue when the expected output will be over 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (for `long`) or 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (for `ulong`)

You can also go a bit further by using the `double` type (±1.7 × 10^308)